# normalize words by meaning

Tags: nlp, nltk, normalize

I am working on a sentence analysis, where I understand the sentence and decipher the information to key value pairs.
like for eg

```
{ "product" : "milk" , "money": "200 usd" }

{ "product" : "chair" , "cost": "200 usd" }

{ "product" : "chair" , "price": "200 usd" }
```

Now this json out put is not easy to use unless I normalize it.
I want to normalize all the words which mean money to a common word say money.

```
{ "product" : "milk" , "money": "200 usd" }

{ "product" : "chair" , "money": "200 usd" }

{ "product" : "chair" , "money": "200 usd" }
```

so now all mean

money, cost, price all actually mean money.

Is there was way to normalize like this ?
I searched for in  nltk there was stemmer and lemmatizer. But it does not seem to do my meaning. Can someone guide ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use NLTK and look each key up in the WordNet [synonym set](http://www.nltk.org/howto/wordnet.html) and take a canonical entry, say the first one, for each.

That probably works well enough if your corpus is fairly general, however if you expect much technical language you might have to generate your own word embeddings or clusters to solve this issue.

Comment: Good suggestion. The OP is probably working in a specific domain, so they might already have a list of the "canonical entries" to target.